# PHPUnit Testing Interactions of Multiple Objects

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following code that I want to ensure always gets called in the proper order:

```php
class ProcessManager {
    // injected via DI
    protected $service1;
    protected $service2;
    protected $service3;

    public function run() {
        $service1->execute();
        $service2->execute();
        $service3->execute();
    }
}
```

I was thinking about mocking out all the services and using `$this->at()`, but that only seems to work if it is multiple functions from the same object. Any ideas how to assert that the different functions from different objects are called in order?

Answer (score 0):

Create the mocks using Mockery, as it supports expectations that should be called in order in distinct mocks. The trick is the "globally()" method:

```
use \Mockery as m;

....

// create the mocks that will be injected:

$service1 = m::mock('Service1Class')
     ->shouldReceive('execute')
     ->once()
     ->globally()
     ->ordered()
     ->getMock();

$service2 = m::mock('Service2Class')
     ->shouldReceive('execute')
     ->once()
     ->globally()
     ->ordered()
     ->getMock();
```

This is all explained at the [Mockery expectations docs.](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/blob/master/docs/06-EXPECTATION%20DECLARATIONS.md)

If you don't want to use Mockery, you can use naive Mocks (real classes that extend the original class) and implement some sort of manual calls order checking (and then calling parent::method if required).

Comment: Looks great, but I wish there was a native phpunit solution. I'm not too keen about including more dependencies on my project.

Comment: I've added another possible way of doing that without any mocking library. Anyway the "not more dependencies" clause was not in the question so...